# sf::Window and sf::RenderTexture throw access violation exception in debug mode, but work fine in release (Visual Studio 2022)

Tags: c++, sfml, visual-studio-2022

I get following error when running my program : `Exception thrown at 0x00007FFB4E3DFAAD (ntdll.dll) in sfwindow_test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000008.`, debugger points at the end of this function in `SFML\System\Win32\MutexImpl.cpp`:

```
void MutexImpl::lock()
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&m_mutex);
}
```

**However, when I switch to Release, it runs and exits without any errors.**

Here are my linker inputs for Debug:

```
winmm.lib
sfml-system-s-d.lib
sfml-window-s-d.lib
opengl32.lib
gdi32.lib
freetype.lib
```

and for Release:

```
winmm.lib
sfml-system-s.lib
sfml-window-s.lib
opengl32.lib
gdi32.lib
freetype.lib
```

Source code:

```
#include <SFML\Window.hpp>

sf::Window window;

int main()
{
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");

    // run the program as long as the window is open
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // "close requested" event: we close the window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I also found out that the same error occurs with `sf::RenderTexture`:

```
#include <SFML\Window.hpp>
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

sf::RenderTexture rt;

int main()
{
    rt.create(1, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried wrapping `sf::RenderTexture` in `std::shared_ptr`. It also works fine in Release.

But, in Debug, throws different error when application is closed: `Exception thrown: read access violation. _Mycont was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF7.`, and debugger points at this line in `xtree`:

```
_STL_VERIFY(this->_Ptr != _Mycont->_Myhead, "cannot dereference end map/set iterator");
```

**I tried using raw pointer, and it works fine both in Debug and Release**, but I don't see why i would need to do this, when the original code runs perfectly fine in Release.

I'm actually having this issue in my project at https://github.com/Instackler/BattleFriends, but I didn't use my actual code from there in my question because I was able to replicate this issue perfectly with the (much more condensed) code above.

So my questions are:

1. **Am I not allowed to declare an instance of `sf::Window` or `sf::RenderTexture` globally? Then why does it work in Release mode?**
2. **If this is because of memory pre-initialization in Debug mode, do I have to use the raw pointer approach to be able to use VS22 debugger?**
3. Is this a bug of "VS22 + SFML in static debug mode" combination?
4. Is this a bug of just SFML in static debug mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've stepped onto Static Initialization Order Fiasco (SIOF) landmine. SFML uses a bunch of global variables internally so when yours `sf::Window window;` global variable is getting initialized those SFML variables ([mutex](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/25920bb6d70d8b52835129c65a75d4fb6ec939be/src/SFML/Window/GlContext.cpp#L168) in particular) are not necessary had been initialized yet and access to uninitialized object leads to Undefined Behavior.

So you should get rid of your global variables. You don't need them anyway.

Comment: Please read the full question. Your answer doesn't explain:

Comment: doesn't explain what?

Comment: I wasn't able to fit the full comment here, so please read it here: [link](https://pastebin.com/c4KX7gcW)

Comment: You don't need global variables. Declaring inside of anonymous namespace does not make it less global. Undefined Behavior occurs because during global initialization stage initialization of `window` and `rt` depends on initialization of other global objects in different translation unit. Note that it occurs in **both** Debug and Release builds. The effect may vary though. `rt.create(1, 1);` does not initialize it. In C++ initialization happens strictly during constructor invocation.